# Rails 3.2 : (activerecord) How do I model this?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, model, tree

### [image]

I have three models: `RequestForQuote`, `CounterQuote < RequestForQuote [inherit RequestForQuote]` and `Proposition`.

A `request_for_quote` has_many `propositions`, and a `proposition` can act as a tree with a `counter_quote`.

I already have :

```
class RequestForQuote < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :propositions, :dependent => :destroy
end

class CounterQuote < RequestForQuote

end

class Proposition < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :request_for_quote
end
```

How can I model it ? Thanks.

Comment: Not sure if I understand but, class Proposition; has_one :counter_quote end; will that not help?

Comment: I'd probably merge `CounterQuote` and `RequestForQuote` to `Quote`. For recursive querying, you'll have to use recursive views in SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a Proposition can have only one CounterQuote, you can use this:

```
class RequestForQuote < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :propositions, :dependent => :destroy
end

class CounterQuote < RequestForQuote
  belongs_to :proposition
end

class Proposition < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :request_for_quote
  has_one :counter_quote
end
```

CounterQuote would have attributes `proposition` and `propositions`, which is not very clear, consider renaming of these.

If CounterQuote can have many propositions, I agree with Tass, you can merge CounterQuote and RequestForQuote. If you need a tree structure (with parent and children), look at existing gems like [awesome_nested_set](https://github.com/collectiveidea/awesome_nested_set).